# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): stripe.redirectToCheckout is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Stripe checkout for a website. Unfortunately, the Stripe docs are very incomplete. I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';

const stripe = loadStripe('pk_test_key');

const handleClick = async (event) => {
  stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    lineItems: [
      {price: 'price_something', quantity: 1},
    ],
    mode: 'subscription',
    successUrl: 'https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    cancelUrl: 'https://example.com/cancel',
  }).then(function(result){
    alert(result);
  });
};

export default function Stripe(){
  return (
    <button role="link" onClick={handleClick}>
      Checkout
    </button>
  );
}
```

I click the button and I get an error: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): stripe.redirectToCheckout is not a function`

My key is correct one but I cannot find any information in their docs or anywhere else to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding that `loadStripe` returns a `Promise` so try to wait for it resolved:

```
const handleClick = async (event) => {
  const stripe = await loadStripe('pk_test_key');

  stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    // ...
  })
};
```

Comment: Ah, that was it. I was trying to generate that outside of the handleClick function like it says to do in the docs and await isn't allowed there.

Answer (score -1):

it help check that  you are using proper await keyword as I had missed that and wondering for 2 hours where's the mistake

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).